# Sorting an output file A-Z

Tags: python, sorting

1.) I'm trying to take input from a file specified as the first argument on the command line. (working)
2.) Remove all line starting with "#" (working)
3.) Sorting the remaining lines A-Z (Not-working)
4.) Writes its output to a file named for the input file with the current time appended. (working)

How can I get point 3 working?

```
import sys
from datetime import *
arg = sys.argv[1]
out_file = str(arg) + "." + datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open((out_file), 'w') as fout:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        if i == 0 or not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
#            line = sorted(out_file())
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this

```py
import sys
from datetime import *
arg = sys.argv[1]
out_file = str(arg) + "." + datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")

result = []

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open((out_file), 'w') as fout:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        if i == 0 or not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
             result.append(line)
    result = sorted(result)
    for line in result:
         fout.write(line)
```

What you did wrong in your example is, that you tried to sort a single line, instead of all lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using either the method `fin.readlines()` or the instruction `list(fin)` which returns a list including all the lines of the file. Then you can use the `sorted` built-in methods to sort this list (or do anything you want to filter this list) before writing in the output file.
Here is an example of solution, very close to your original code:

```
import sys
from datetime import *
arg = sys.argv[1]
out_file = str(arg) + "." + datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open((out_file), 'w') as fout:
    lines = sorted(list(fin))
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 0 or not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
            fout.write(line)
```

I can also suggest you this solution:

```
import sys
from datetime import *
arg = sys.argv[1]
out_file = str(arg) + "." + datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open((out_file), 'w') as fout:  
    lines = list(fin)          # Get the list of all lines
    fout.write(lines.pop(0))   # Write the 1st line (and remove from list)
    lines = sorted(lines)      # Sort A-Z
    lines = [s for s in lines if not s.lstrip().startswith('#')] # Remove lines starting with '#'
    fout.write(''.join(lines)) # Write the lines
```

Answer (score 0):

This version of the code:

- writes the first line by advancing the `fin` [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)
- uses the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function to remove the lines starting with 
  '#'<sup>1</sup>

  - the first line is not included in the filter, because the `fin` iterator has moved past it
- sorts the filtered lines, to minimise the amount of sorting to be done<sup>2</sup>

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open((out_file), 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(next(fin))
    filtered = filter(lambda x: not x.lstrip().startswith('#'), fin)
    lines = sorted(filtered)
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

<sup>1</sup> You could use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here instead of `filter`

<sup>2</sup>The code assumes that every line ends with a newline